# const std::unordered_map<char, int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I am now sorting a string in decreasing order based on the frequency of characters. For example: the input is "apple", I must output "ppale". Because character 'p' appears twice and the others only appear once. so 'p' must be placed to the left most.

Here is my code:

```
string frequencySort(string s) {
    if(s.size() == 0)   return "";

    unordered_map<char,int> map;
    for(auto c : s)
        map[c]++;   //record the frequency of each characters

    sort(s.begin(),s.end(),
        [=](char a, char b){return map[a] > map[b] || map[a]==map[b]&&a<b;}
        );
    return s;
}
```

But compiler shows error: 
`passing ‘const std::unordered_map<char, int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers` on `[=](char a, char b){return map[a] > map[b] || map[a]==map[b]&&a<b;}`.

However, if I capture local variable by reference, i.e.

`[&](char a, char b){return map[a] > map[b] || map[a]==map[b]&&a<b;}`

it works.

Could anyone please tell my why I cannot capture by value?

Comment: Nit picking here: Apparently, you *probably* have a `using namespace std` somewhere in your code. I will be weary of using `map` for a variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda's `operator (...)` is `const` by default. Capture by value will require the lambda to keep copies of all captured objects.

Make the lambda `mutable` to allow modifying value captures.

```
sort(s.begin(),s.end(), [=](char a, char b) mutable 
          {return map[a] > map[b] || map[a]==map[b]&&a<b;}
    );
```

---

I suspect the `sort` and `unordered_map` is from the namespace `std`. From the way you used them without a namespace resolution, you *probably* have a `using namespace std` in your code (which [isn't nice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). I will be weary of using `map` for a variable name.

Comment: yap, `sort` and `unordered_map` are from `std` and I have a `using namespace std`. Thanks for your suggestion!